# Data manipulation in Dropdownlist using DataSource

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datasource, dropdown

I have this DropDowList which is using DataSource to display all the items. Which is using this query:

```
Select distinct [Word] from [Book] order by [Word]
```

Let's assume that the the query display this following words.

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Mango
4. Banana
5. Pineapple

Now my problem is I want to convert all the Data displaying in the RadiobuttonList to a specific text that I want. For Example , the word Banana to its Spanish word Platano.

Below is the DropDown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FruitDD" runat="server" DataSourceID="FruitSource" DataTextField="Value" DataValueField="Code" AppendDataBoundItems="True"> <asp:ListItem>- Select Fruit</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the code I am using to convert.

```
FruitDD.Items[1].Text = "[string that I want]";
```

Which is causing error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Is there an effective way that I can convert this using the DataSource?

Comment: Check out how many items in FruitDD. The index of item can't be greater than or equal to the count of item

Answer (score 0):

I already have an answer.

```
FruitDD.DataBind();
FruitDD.Items[number].Text = "[string]";
```